# Missing Editor, in Appearance Wordpress theme Activello

Tags: wordpress, editor, footer

I have a little problem with wordpress theme Activello.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP6US.jpg

I can't found in Appearance sumbmenu Editor. I need it for edit footer theme because for the moment it's looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHYQI.jpg

Thanks for your attention.

Wish you a good day!

Comment: you can see all menu items in "menus"

Comment: Yes I can see them. https://imgur.com/a/RELb9Hk

Comment: just drap and drop left to right the 2nd menu item

Comment: George I don't need to edit position of menu and submenu. I need to fix the problem with missing Editor in Wordpress Dashboard in Appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in wp-config.php file

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, its due to some of your security plugins like - https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/. Check settings of each and every security plugin you have installed.

Comment: Okay. I'll check them now! Thanks.

Comment: Outsource WordPress can you tell me please, what plugin can give me this trouble.
On my site I use this list of plugins: 
a3 Lazy Load,
Akismet Anti-Spam,
Akismet Privacy Policies,
Autoptimize,
Child Theme Condifgurator,
COnditional Widgets,
Contact Form 7,
Contact Form 7 Widget for Elementor page builder,
Custom Fonts,
Easy Google Fonts,
Elementor,
Elementor Addon Elements,
Elementor Addons & Templates - Sizzify Lite,
Force Regenerate Thumbnails,
Hide Page and Post Title,
NavMenu Addon For Elementor,
PopBox for Elementor,
Really Simple CAPTCHA,

Comment: reGenerate Thumbnails - advanced, Shariff Wrapper, Smart Slider 3, Smush, TinyMCE Advanced, Webcraftic Clearfy, Widget Importer & Exporter, WP Meta and Date Remover, WP Super Cache

Comment: I didn't use wordpress for a long time and forgot how to use it right. Thanks for help

Comment: Can you just rename 'plugins' folder and check whether Editor menu showing? Sometimes theme settings may also disable the Editor menu access.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution. This video will help you. You can change or delete footer credits: https://youtube.com/watch?v=fVm2eenrgkE. Or you can go to to customise > css and find div class of credits. Then in css box type this:
.{display:none;}

Comment: Mario, I've seen this video, but it didn't help. I don't want to delete my footer, I just need to edit it. Cause I can't edit .php files without editor.

Comment: But, you can change it. If you want, I can do it for you, but you will need to give me login credentials. You can also contact me by mail: mario.mlinaric7@yahoo.com and I can like connect to you with TeamViewer, and fix it. (If you want.)